# Inheritance: Child methods referring to parent variables

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I probably butchered class inheritance, however I'm trying to define a child class method, but in that method use variables stored as a constituent of the parent class.

In this way:

```
#include "TrainingAspects.h"

class Train
{
private:

    vector<vector<Point> > ptContours;        // declare contours vector
    vector<Vec4i> v4iHierarchy;               // declare contours hierarchy

public:
    TrainingAspects trainingAspectsClass = TrainingAspects();
};
```

```
class TrainingAspects : public Train
{
private:


public:

    void trainingAspects();
};
```

```
#include "Train.h"
#include "Constants.h"


void TrainingAspects::trainingAspects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->ptContours.size(); i++)
    {
      // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Doing the normal inheritance method doesn't work and I get the error "*TrainingAspects* has no member *ptContours*".

In my code I have stored information in ptContours in a *Train* method, using this->ptContours = *stuff*, and I'm trying to access that same information from the child class.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Make the members protected rather than private?

Comment: Are trying to make a virtual aka abstract base class or an interface or something like that? What is the point of `TrainingAspects trainingAspectsClass = TrainingAspects();`? This will not work and makes me curious what you are actually trying to achieve.